# Why is setting a checkbox's false value to 'undefined' causing ng-invalid to get added

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a checkbox in angular that has a false value of `undefined` and despite it not being `required`, my form does not validate when it is checked and unchecked, due to `ng-invalid` being added as a class to the input on uncheck.

Why does this happen?

Here is a plunker you can mess with:
http://plnkr.co/edit/mFVcW1pI4wxf5lzRWoZE?p=preview

Notice the second checkbox has a false value of 'undefined'.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value" ng-true-value="'hi'" ng-false-value="undefined" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
```

Turns into

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value" ng-true-value="'hi'" ng-false-value="undefined" class="ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-invalid-parse ng-touched">
```

When unchecked, even though neither `required` nor `ng-required` are present

Comment: Please post relevant code in the question.

Comment: You need to wrap it in single quotes I believe. Like this ng-false-value="'undefined'"    " 'all the things here' "

Comment: I had an answer up, using `ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }"`... but it doesn't actually work as I thought it did, so I deleted that answer. Anyway, the problem you're getting is a `parse` error. Whenever a $parser returns undefined, that's a `parse` error. So you can either use another value (like `null`) or figure out why `allowInvalid: true` doesn't work.

Comment: Added code to question. @Yeysides I want the value to be undefined, not a string that says 'undefined'.

Comment: @HankScorpio you can post that as the answer and I'll accept. I can use null instead.

Comment: @TomSlick is this checkbox going to have three values? As in will you have a 'Y', 'N', AND an 'undefined'? Because if not I would use ternary upon form submission to force it to pass undefined or w.e you need. (ex: $scope.formName.fieldName ? $scope.formName.fieldName : undefined) So in other words I'd have ng-false-value be nothing, that way you can use this logic because I'm pretty sure the undefined is throwing that exception. Worth a try.

Comment: Ok, thanks TomSlick. I've just done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a $parser returns `undefined`, that's considered a parse error. You could use another value instead (like null).

ngModelOptions.allowInvalid should allow undefined to work... but I tested it and it still has the validation error. *shrug*